# Recieving RTSP stream With JavaCV Library

Tags: java, streaming, rtsp, javacv, ip-camera

I am currently trying to obtain an RTSP stream from an IP camera on my network so that I can apply facial recognition algorithms to the frames (I am using the JavaCV library for this).

When I attempt to obtain the RTSP stream, I start getting an error depending upon the method that I tried to use.

Here is the code that should work:

```
try {
    FFmpegFrameGrabber streamGrabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber("rtsp://admin:12345@(ip)/ch1/main/av_stream");
    streamGrabber.setFormat("h264");
    streamGrabber.setFrameRate(30);
    streamGrabber.setImageWidth(getWidth());
    streamGrabber.setImageHeight(getHeight());
    streamGrabber.start();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

That particular piece of code gives me this error:

```
org.bytedeco.javacv.FrameGrabber$Exception: avformat_open_input() error -1330794744: Could not open input "rtsp://admin:12345@192.168.64.96/ch1/main/av_stream". (Has setFormat() been called?)
    at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber.startUnsafe(FFmpegFrameGrabber.java:393)
    at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber.start(FFmpegFrameGrabber.java:341)
    at main.FaceApplet.init(FaceApplet.java:87)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:425)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

I have tried:

- Using OpenCVFrameGrabber instead - error says "Could not create camera capture"
- Using IPCameraFrameGrabber - requires http url
- Changing Protocol:

  - FTP: Authentication Failed
  - TCP: Freezes the program
  - UDP: Authentication Failed

What am I doing wrong, is this a code issue or a camera issue?

Comment: Hey, just a heads up: you should post the "update" part of your post as an answer and remove it from the question (yes, you can answer your own question.) It makes it easier to read (especially to e.g. other services that hitch into SO's API.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

I Finally got it working... the magic formula seems to be using the FFMpeggrabber to obtain a stream... to avoid the error, just don't set the video format using the function. Initializer code should look something like this:

```
streamGrabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber("rtsp://admin:12345@(ip):554/live.sdp");
streamGrabber.setFrameRate(30);
streamGrabber.setImageWidth(getWidth());

try {
    streamGrabber.start();
} catch (FrameGrabber.Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I'm facing an issue, if I save this stream in a file, I'm unable to play it using ffplay or mpv, It shows an invalid header/moov element, any suggestions?